# Joins with CanCan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to RoR and Ruby in general, so forgive me if my understanding of syntax isn't too great. I'm utilizing CanCan for authorizing certain abilities, obviously, and I would like to limit a user to view only his/her own schedule.

In my Schedule model, I have

```
belongs_to:camp
```

I theorize that I could utilize something like the following (given that id is an attribute of the user)

```
can :read, Schedule, current_user.user_id => user.id
```

I'm also using Devise if that changes anything.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track...  In your controller, you'd `authorize! :read, @schedule` (or use `load_and_authorize_resource` for the whole controller, then in `ability.rb`, you'd want to do something like:

```
can :read, Schedule do |schedule|
  user.id == schedule.user_id
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The ["hash of conditions"](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/defining-abilities) that cancan accepts refer to conditions that may be used to filter records with the class in question.  In this case, you want to specify conditions relevant to the Schedule class.  For example, if user_id is an attribute of Schedule then the ability should read

```
can :read, Schedule :user_id => user.id
```

(CanCan will pass you the current user as a local variable named user)

Answer (score 0):

Just try this :

can :read, Schedule, :user_id => user.id